# puzzled about a statement in Deligne's notes on Drinfel'd modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading "Survey of Drinfel'd modules" by Pierre Deligne and Dale Husemöller. There is a statement in Section 3 of Chapter 1 which is puzzling me a bit at the moment.

They let $G$ be the group scheme $G_{a}$ over a field $k$ which is an extension of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, such that the group $G_{a}(R)$ is the additive group of $R$ for any commutative unitary $k$-algebra $R$, and they define $\mathrm{End}_{k}(G)$ to be the ring of group scheme $k$-morphisms from $G$ into $G$. Then they let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ with an $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-rational point $\infty$ and let $A$ be the co-ordinate ring over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ of $C\setminus\{\infty\}$, and consider a ring morphism $\phi:A\rightarrow\mathrm{End}_{k}(G)$ such that $\partial_{0}\circ\phi$ is injective where $\partial_{0}$ sends an element of $\mathrm{End}_{k}(G)$ viewed as a polynomial with coefficients in $k$ to the value of the derivative at the origin. Then they view $G(\overline{k})$ as an $A$-module and they consider the group of all points $x\in G(\overline{k})$ which are annihilated by some proper nonzero ideal $I$ of $A$. They seem to be claiming that this is always a free $A/I$-module regardless of the choice of ideal $I$. I'm not sure why this is true. Seems to me that that could only work if $G(\overline{k})$ was a torsion-free $A$-module.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. I have just realized that they prove the statement as Theorem 3.3. So if I had just looked ahead a bit there would have been no need to ask the question.